# How to update HTML table When updating Firebase?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using child_added and child_changed. The child added works perfectly fine, but the child_changed makes a duplicate in my table. Please help me overcome this. Here is my code:

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("REPORTS").child(date);

rootRef.on("child_added", function(snapshot){
    var date = snapshot.child("dateAndTime").val();
    var lat = snapshot.child("latitude").val();
    var long = snapshot.child("longitude").val();
    var link = snapshot.child("link").val();
    var report = snapshot.child("report").val();
    var status = snapshot.child("status").val();
    var needs = snapshot.child("needs").val();


    $("#table_body").append("<tr><td>" +date+"</td><td>"+report+"</td><td>"+lat+"</td><td>"+long+"</td><td>"+status+"</td><td>"+needs+"</tr>");

});

rootRef.on("child_changed", function(snapshot){
    var date = snapshot.child("dateAndTime").val();
    var lat = snapshot.child("latitude").val();
    var long = snapshot.child("longitude").val();
    var link = snapshot.child("link").val();
    var report = snapshot.child("report").val();
    var status = snapshot.child("status").val();
    var needs = snapshot.child("needs").val();


    $("#table_body").append("<tr><td>" +date+"</td><td>"+report+"</td><td>"+lat+"</td><td>"+long+"</td><td>"+status+"</td><td>"+needs+"</tr>");

});
```

How can I update my table when a certain value was updated in firebase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of **appending** a new HTML element, the code that handles `child_changed` should **update** the existing HTML element. The easiest way to do this is by ensuring you give the HTML element an `id` based on `snapshot.key` in `child_added`:

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("REPORTS").child(date);

rootRef.on("child_added", function(snapshot){
    var date = snapshot.child("dateAndTime").val();
    var lat = snapshot.child("latitude").val();
    var long = snapshot.child("longitude").val();
    var link = snapshot.child("link").val();
    var report = snapshot.child("report").val();
    var status = snapshot.child("status").val();
    var needs = snapshot.child("needs").val();


    $("#table_body").append("<tr id='"+snapshot.key+"'><td>" +date+"</td><td>"+report+"</td><td>"+lat+"</td><td>"+long+"</td><td>"+status+"</td><td>"+needs+"</tr>");

});
```

Then you can look the element up by its id/key in `child_changed` and update it:

```
rootRef.on("child_changed", function(snapshot){
    var date = snapshot.child("dateAndTime").val();
    var lat = snapshot.child("latitude").val();
    var long = snapshot.child("longitude").val();
    var link = snapshot.child("link").val();
    var report = snapshot.child("report").val();
    var status = snapshot.child("status").val();
    var needs = snapshot.child("needs").val();


    $("#"+snapshot.key).replaceWith("<tr id='"+snapshot.key+"'><td>" +date+"</td><td>"+report+"</td><td>"+lat+"</td><td>"+long+"</td><td>"+status+"</td><td>"+needs+"</tr>");

});
```

Comment: thanks sir. You're answer was very clear. Now it works fine.